# TFS - Set permission for specific project within team project

Tags: tfs, permissions

we use TFS-2010. we have one Team project under Project collection. and we have 15 Project under team project. now another team (not company employee) is going to join from remote location. and they are going to work on one specific project.
**Problem:**
so i would like to do is to set permission in a such a way that they should see only that particular project, rest 14 project should be hidden from them(not even able to check out or get source any how).
 TFS server currently runs on premises. and we are accessing it as Domain uses.
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can select any folder in source control explorer, right-click, properties, Security tab, and restrict or grant rights to each specific folder by roles.

This way you could create a new TFS Security Role, call it Consultants (from Team -> Team Project Settings -> Group Membership -> New...).  Grant it access to the appropriate folders then assign all your consultants domain accounts to it.

Comment: thanks Dylan, as per your instruction, i have created a new role. but when i tried to connect to TFS server from VS2010 , i cant see team project under collection, should i set permission for that as well?

Comment: it turns out i had to apple same permission at the project level. now everything worked.

Answer (score 4):

What we do at work when consultants need access to our source control is to create a new branch with the code they are going to work on, and grant them permissions to just that one branch. Your group could also work out of that branch and merge back into your main branch when appropriate.

Comment: thanks hawkke, will creating a new branch will create new collection? (sorry i am newbi in TFS)

Comment: @nnp no. You will create the new branch inside your existing Team Project. Just add a new folder in your Team Project (the TFS project, not the visual studio project), turn it into a branch, and create a new Visual Studio solution with the code you want inside the branch. Then apply security to that branch.