# TFS - Permission for specific project

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

This is the extension of the following Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619445/tfs-set-permission-for-specific-project-within-team-project)

Scenario:

- Visual Studio Solution has projects A, B & C.
- Project A is core library used by B & C.
- Remote employee has permission to access only project C (which needs project A).

Question:

- How can remote employee build and test project C which references project A, while remote employee has permission to access only project C.
- Is it necessary to share project A with remote employee or is there any way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove Project A from the solution.  Obviously, the other projects would still need the relevant dlls.

If there is very sensitive information in project A then I have the following suggestion (of course this will depend on your architecture):

1. Create a public interface for project A, put this in Project D or something.
2. Make project A use this, then create a mock for the Project A interface and provide this project instead.

This would give all the dependencies necessary, and mean that you don't have to provide the dependant dlls.  It is also good practice for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, you need to

- Move project C out of the solution into a solution of its own.
- Change the project reference from C to A to a binary reference so that C references the compiled output of A. In order to do this, place A.dll in a directory under the newly created C-solution. Also add A.dll to source control so that the remote employee can retrieve the solution and A.dll from source control.
- If you make changes to A that are required in project C, you need to check out A.dll, substitute it by the new version and check it in again.

Of course this means that the effort is higher if you want to propagate changes made to project A to the newly created C-solution. But it separates the environments cleanly from one another.

This approach also works if you want to follow the excellent [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22590168/642579) of @pm_2 about extracting the relevant interface of A and provide only a mock version to the remote employee. In this case, you place the interface dll and the mock version to source control.

Comment: As you suggested A.dll should be kept in sync with project C. For this i have to manually check in A.dll. Is there automated way to do this. For example Maven is used in Java Project, which downloads updated dependence from central repo.

Comment: @Anji: I don't know of an easy way to automate this. You can customize your build process to achieve this, but it requires some effort. Maybe there is a .Net implementation of Maven?